# Receiving udp packet on designated network card c#

Tags: c#, udp, udpclient, nic

I have 3 different network cards each with their individual responsibility. Two of the cards are receiving packets from a similar device (plugged directly into each individual network card) which sends data on the same port. I need to save the packets knowing which device they came from.

Given that I am required to not specify the ip address of the devices sending me the packets, how can I listen on a given network card? I am allowed to specify a static ip address for all 3 nics if needed.

Example: nic1 = 169.254.0.27, nic2 = 169.254.0.28, nic3 = 169.254.0.29

Right now I have this receiving the data from nic1 and nic2 without knowing which device it came from.

```
var myClient = new UdpClient(2000) //Port is random example

var endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0):

while (!finished)
{
    byte[] receivedBytes = myClient.Receive(ref endPoint);
    doStuff(receivedBytes);
}
```

I can't seem to specify the static ip address of the network cards in a manner which will allow me to capture the packets from just one of the devices. How can I separate these packets with only the knowledge that they are coming in on two different network cards?

Thank you.

Comment: guess what happens if you replace IPAddress.Any with an IP address of the two cards?

Comment: @DavidePiras I've tested that, and I still receive packets from both devices. Is there something else I have to specify along with changing the ip there?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're not telling the UdpClient what IP endpoint to listen on. Even if you were to replace `IPAddress.Any` with the endpoint of your network card, you'd still have the same problem.

If you want to tell the UdpClient to receive packets on a specific network card, you have to specify the IP address of that card in the *constructor*. Like so:

```
var listenEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.2"), 2000);
var myClient = new UdpClient(listenEndpoint);
```

Now, you may ask "What's the `ref endPoint` part for when I'm calling `myClient.Receive(ref endPoint)`?" That endpoint is the IP endpoint of the *client*. I would suggest replacing your code with something like this:

```
IPEndpoint clientEndpoint = null;

while (!finished)
{
    var receivedBytes = myClient.Receive(ref clientEndpoint);
    // clientEndpoint is no longer null - it is now populated
    // with the IP address of the client that just sent you data
}
```

So now you have two endpoints:

1. `listenEndpoint`, passed in through the constructor, specifying the address of the network card you want to listen on.
2. `clientEndpoint`, passed in as a ref parameter to Receive(), which will be [populated with the client's IP address](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.receive.aspx) so you know who is talking to you.

Comment: Well explained! That was the simple bit I wasn't grasping. Thank you for the help.

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  I've tried doing as you suggested here: UdpClient listener = new UdpClient(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("10.1.1.1"), listenPort));

However, it is listening on an incorrect network card.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out this:

```
  foreach (NetworkInterface netInterface in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Name: " + netInterface.Name);
    Console.WriteLine("Description: " + netInterface.Description);
    Console.WriteLine("Addresses: ");
    IPInterfaceProperties ipProps = netInterface.GetIPProperties();
    foreach (UnicastIPAddressInformation addr in ipProps.UnicastAddresses)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(" " + addr.Address.ToString());
    }
    Console.WriteLine("");
  }
```

Then you can choose on which address start listening.

Comment: This will simply give me the static ips which I already know. I do know how to access the cards. I don't know how to create a udp client that only listens on one of those cards. :)

Comment: So binding to selected IP and port is not working, I thought that you could get Ip from this list programmatcaly and use in creating endpoint instead of Any adress.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working how I am currently doing it. I think I am missing something small...

Answer (score 0):

look, if you create your `IPEndPoint` in the following way it must work:

```
IPHostEntry hostEntry = null;

// Get host related information.
hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(server);

foreach(IPAddress address in hostEntry.AddressList)
{
  IPEndPoint ipe = new IPEndPoint(address, port);
  ...
```

try to do not pass `0` as port but a valid port number, if you run this code and break the foreach after the first iteration you will have created only 1 `IPEndPoint` and you can use that one in your call to: `myClient.Receive`

notice that the `UdpClient` class has a member calledd Client which is a socket, try to explore the properties of that object as well to find out some details, I have found the code I gave you here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx